# Setting up custom conda channel for offline environment installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, channel, conda-build

I am trying to set up a custom channel to install and manage a python environment on several offline computers. I am following the instructions [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html). I have completed steps 1 (install conda-build) and 2 (organize packages). However attempting step 3 on the offline machine with a miniconda python 3.10 build results in several problems.

First, conda-build is missing dependencies. I addressed two of these by installing pyyaml and python-libarchive-c. However, python-libarchive-c needs an archive.dll and I cannot find a recompiled 64bit dll.

My questions are two fold. 1) is there an easier way to setup and maintain offline environments? 2) has anyone setup an offline custom conda channel and have instructions or guidance?

Comment: One needs to download all dependencies, not just the packages you desire. The scripts in this answer might be useful for grabbing all the files needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210871/570918