# How to install .conda file downloaded from anaconda package site?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

For example, I want to install fish shell using conda. But the server has no internet connection.

On https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fish/files , many versions are provided. But almost the latest few versions are always in .conda format.

I downloaded `linux-64/fish-3.7.0-hdab1d28_0.conda` and install it using

```
conda install linux-64/fish-3.7.0-hdab1d28_0.conda
```

But this does not work. It shows a long error report like

```
...    
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'...../miniconda3/pkgs/linux-64_fzf-0.46.1-ha8f183a_0/info/repodata_record.json'
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...../miniconda3/pkgs/linux-64_fzf-0.46.1-ha8f183a_0/info/index.json'
....
etc
```

But old version in tar.gz format like `linux-64/fish-3.4.1-h682823d_0.tar.bz2` installed just fine.

So how to correctly conda install .conda file?

Comment: @merv Thank you so much! Rename `linux-64_fzf-0.46.1-ha8f183a_0.conda` to `fzf-0.46.1-ha8f183a_0.conda` works great!

Comment: Great to hear that was it! Admittedly that was a long-shot guess. I went ahead and converted it to a proper answer. I'd kindly ask that you also make a comment on the GitHub Issue, even just to note that you also encountered the problem, so that the maintainers can properly prioritize getting it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bug with Anaconda Cloud downloads

There is [an outstanding bug with the Anaconda Cloud website](https://github.com/conda/infrastructure/issues/868) that prepends the subdirectory (e.g., a `linux-64_` prefix) to file names when downloading from a browser (i.e., clicking file links). This is fine for `.tar.gz` files, but for `.conda` the file name is coupled(!) to being able to correctly unpack the archive.

Error in OP shows a reference to `linux-64_fzf-0.46.1-ha8f183a_0`, which implies a `linux-64_fzf-0.46.1-ha8f183a_0.conda` file is being unpacked. However, the file name should likely not have the `linux-64_` prefix. Try renaming the file to `fzf-0.46.1-ha8f183a_0.conda`.

Note that programmatically downloading the `.conda` files (e.g., with `curl`, `wget`) will not have this problem, so one may also be interested in downloading archives *en masse*, like what is provided for in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210871/570918).